# Linking 3rd Party Framework in XCode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use the spotify API in my app. I've downloaded the .framework files, and placed them in my XCode project. However, I can't find the option to link them, and in any case, import fails to recognize the module. In most tutorials I've seen, they have a tab for this in the project page, but I only have options for "Info" and "Build Settings". I added the module names to the "Prelink Libraries" section, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The window which has only `Info` and `Build Setting` is `PROJECT`. If you select a specific target, you will see what you want.

Comment: Ryan is correct, you must select a Target first. Under the General tab, scroll down to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". If the section is not open, click the disclosure triangle. If the library is not in the list, click the + button to add  your framework.